# Install4j console handler for directory selection

Tags: console, install4j

My app has an installation directory chooser form. It validates whether dir has required available space. Screen looks like:

1. some text
2. Dir chooser component
3. A label which prints the available disk space. This is bound to a context variable availableSpace.

Disk space is calculated in "validation expression".

This works correctly in UI mode. In console mode - the behaviour is:

- A. #1 is shown.
- B. #2 asks user to select dir
  (user selects a dir)
- C. #3 shows the label text. Since there is no calculation done yet, availableSpace is not updated yet. User sees an old value.
- D. Validation logic triggers and the UI is rerendered.
- E. #1 is shown. #2 is shown and user enters the dir again. #3 shows the value which was set in #C.

From UI's perspective the form has already calculated data so #C is correct. 
But from console user's perspective, user entered a dir and so #C is confusing to user. Because he just entered a dir and space value is old. He thinks that the dir has space, why is application shows old value ?

How to fix this behaviour ?

- One solutionis to not show #C on console mode and instead use a Util.showMessage().
- Can ConsoleHandlerFormComponent solve this ?
- Is there a handler for DirectoryChooserComponent selection ? That can check for space in real time.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In console mode, the "Validation script" property of the "Installation directory chooser" form component is executed as soon as you confirm the selection.

The problem in your case is that the label is not updated. This is because form components are initialized only once at the time that the screen is created. You can call

```
formEnvironment.reinitializeFormComponents();
```

in the "Validation script", then the contents of the label will be evaluated again.